# Code coverage not working TFS build

Tags: code-coverage, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have enabled the code coverage in the build definition for a project in TFS. 
[image]

It's building as expected, unit tests are running as well but code coverage shows "No build coverage data available" see the screenshot below.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question to you. But you did not mention your licence version. As I understood it MS Code Coverage is only available for Enterprise Version of VS/TFS. I always found it very confusing that the feature can be ticked on, but shows no results in the Professional Version.

Comment: @RobertK thank you for the feedback. Our TFS version says "Team Foundation Server 2015". I don't think we have the enterprise edition of the TFS.

Comment: I think there is no prof/enterprise flavor on TFS. But it would need at least one enterprise edition of Visual Studio on its build agent.
To overcome this I am using the open source alternative [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover).
And I wrote a small 'learning project' to integrate this with TFS 2015. If you are interested give it a try and/or join me there ;-): https://github.com/RobertK66/vsts-opencover

Comment: @RobertK, Thank you very much for the offer. I will give it a go as soon as i have some spare time. :-)

Comment: @mahfuz01 - I have the exact same problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 7):

The coverage result is just a file with `*.coverage` extension.

So enabling `Code Coverage Enabled` checkbox is not enough.
This checkbox enables calculating of code coverage and producing this file.

However to attach this `*.coverage` file to a build, you also need to enable `Upload Test Attachments` checkbox under `Reporting Options` section.
Please see the image attached.

[image: Reporting Options: Upload Test Attachments]
This checkbox enables exactly what you need, it will publish coverage result against with the build.

And the final log should look something like this:

```
2016-10-17T15:47:03.6834453Z Attachments:
2016-10-17T15:47:03.6834453Z   TFSBUILD 2016-10-17 11_46_53.coverage 
2016-10-17T15:47:03.6834453Z Total tests: Passed: Failed: Skipped:
2016-10-17T15:47:03.6834453Z Test Run Successful.
```

Answer (score 5):

Just test on my side, Code Coverage is available as expected. I'd like to share my steps for your reference:

1. Create a default **Visual Studio** template.
2. Specify the **Solution** in `Visual Studio Build` task, and check the **Code Coverage Enabled** in `Visual Studio Test` task. See the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Other settings are not changed.

3. Queue build, then I can see the Code Coverage shows on build summary:

[image]

By the way, I'm using TFS 2015 Update2.

Comment: Hi @cece-msft that's exactly what I did for my projects. specified the solution path, even selected the test.dll to run. I found somewhere that the tests has to be MSTest not nUnit or xUnit tests. I also have converted all my tests to MSTest. Still no luck. it's getting a bit frustrating

Comment: What kind of project are you testing? Code Coverage Enabled is supported for .net and C++ projects only. You may try to create a light project to test this function.

Comment: Hi @cece-msft my solution is a MVC 4.5 Web Application but the unit tests are done on the business layer (class library). I don't think its a issue for code coverage as I can use resharper to get the code coverage but the project manager wants to view it on the tfs web view as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by checking two check boxing as shown in the picture only enabling Code Coverage is not enough you need to check Upload test attachments as well in the Test Template.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQQAH.png)